# Merge files using created date

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

I have the three sql files in the directory

1.FileA.sql ->Created on Jan10,2014

2.FileB.sql ->Created on Feb10,2014

3.FileX.sql ->Created on Jun25,2014

I want to create a single All.sql file based on created date. Initially it was only two files.

So i tried creating `Merge.bat` file with the following command

```
copy FileA.sql+FileB.sql All.sql
```

How can i merge all the files using created date?

Comment: copy FileA.sql+FileB.sql+FileX.sql JanFebJun.sql

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I have no idea how many files will be created now. It will be placed by some other application. Thats why I asked this question.

Comment: What has the create date got to do with anything? Do you want the scripts in the output file to be sorted by create date? I should think last modified date would be better.

Comment: Can SQL files simply be appended to each other?? Aren't they binary databases?

Answer (score 2):

The following 2 commands issued from the command prompt will produce your desired output, sorting the source files by creation timestamp.

```
for %F in ('dir /b /od /tc *.sql') do (@type "%F"&echo()>>all.sql
```

I put an extra new line between each source script, just in case the last line of a source script is missing the new line.

Double up the percents (`%F` --> `%%F`) if you use the command in a batch script.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set command=copy 
rem leave space at end of above command
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b /od *.sql') do (set command=!command!"%%~i"+)
set command=!command!null all.sql
!command!
```